# Typescript Define value extract from Object

Tags: typescript

I have javascript code like this.

```js
const { a, b, c } = {
    a : "hello",
    b : "stackoverflow",
    c : "it's greate"
};
```

i want to make this as typescript. is there any solution?

Comment: you can already use it it your typescrit files. it is perfectly valid code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As captain-yossarian mentioned, this will also work in typescript. I'd recommend that you start with the basics - meaning just preparing a type for your currently "black box" object (= `a`could be a string, array, whatever):

```
interface SomeType {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: number;
}

const { a, b, c }: SomeType = {
    a : "hello",
    b : "stackoverflow",
    c : "it's greate" // This will not work because c has to be a number!
};
```

Then your IDE/editor will know, that `a` and `b` are strings and that `c` should be a number (and also throw an error because `c` is not a number). This will become crucial when working with more data and bigger codebases.
I really can recommend this (official) guide: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html

Answer (score 0):

It's already a TS valid code! You can use a type for a better code.

```
export type Something = {
   a: string,
   b: number,
   c: Custom
}

const { a, b, c }: Something = {
    a : "hello",
    b : 3,
    c : {}
};
```